# Flattening multidimensional Array keeping keys and values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to flatten a multidimensional array by recursion.
My array looks like

```
$arr_pages = array(
        "index" => array(
                "contenttitle" => "Home",

        ),
        "credentials"                => array(
                "contenttitle" => "Credentials...have a look",
                "sub"          => array(

                    // Second Level
                    "customer"  => array(
                            "contenttitle" => "Customer Projects",
                            "sub" => array(  

                                   "ABC" => array(
                                   "contenttitle" => "ABC Customer",
                            ),
                    ),
           ),

  );
```

I want to keep the data but changig the structure to

```
       "index" => array(
                "contenttitle" => "Home",

        ),
        "credentials" => array(
                "contenttitle" => "Credentials...have a look",


        "customer"  => array(
                "contenttitle" => "Customer Projects",
        )
        "ABC" => array(
             "contenttitle" => "ABC Customer",
         ),
```

So what is the best practice to create a new array with the new structure?

Comment: Best practice? Recursive function.

Comment: @VasilShaddix what is your option?

Comment: Since recursion is legit the only option here. However, in this case you really need to take into account key collision.

Comment: you can use array_walk_recusirve if you want a simply recursive function otherwise you can create your own recursive function